# calling graphql query but getting Undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql

my query

```
const ExamOverviewQuery = gql`
query ($itemId: Int) {
    Exam(filter: { Exam_ID: { _eq: $itemId }}) {
        Exam_ID,
        Exam_Name,
        Exam_State {
            Exam_State_Name
        },
        Exam_Status {
            Exam_Status_Name
        },
        Eligibility_Class,
        Deadline
    }
}`
```

and calling like this

```
let itemId = 1;

console.log(typeof (itemId));

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(ExamOverviewQuery, {
    variables: { itemId: 1 },
});
console.log(data);
console.log(error);
```

not getting the data

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

`useQuery` is async. `data` will be undefined while `loading` is true. If there are no errors then `data` will exist once `loading` becomes false.